# Error ECONNREFUSED after upgrading nextjs 12 to 13

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13

I upgraded from Nextjs 12 to 13 but now everytime I run the application, I'm getting ECONNREFUSED to my local but the port keeps changing. and it won't render

```
> dtpms-usrmgmt-ui@0.1.20 dev /run/media/rud31mp/drive2/Codes/typescript/dtpms/dtpms-usrmngr-ui
> next dev -p 3002

- ready started server on 0.0.0.0:3002, url: http://localhost:3002
- info Loaded env from /run/media/rud31mp/drive2/Codes/typescript/dtpms/dtpms-usrmngr-ui/.env.local
- warn Invalid next.config.js options detected: 
- warn     The root value has an unexpected property, externals, which is not in the list of allowed properties (amp, analyticsId, assetPrefix, basePath, cleanDistDir, compiler, compress, configOrigin, crossOrigin, devIndicators, distDir, env, eslint, excludeDefaultMomentLocales, experimental, exportPathMap, generateBuildId, generateEtags, headers, httpAgentOptions, i18n, images, modularizeImports, onDemandEntries, optimizeFonts, output, outputFileTracing, pageExtensions, poweredByHeader, productionBrowserSourceMaps, publicRuntimeConfig, reactStrictMode, redirects, rewrites, sassOptions, serverRuntimeConfig, skipMiddlewareUrlNormalize, skipTrailingSlashRedirect, staticPageGenerationTimeout, swcMinify, target, trailingSlash, transpilePackages, typescript, useFileSystemPublicRoutes, webpack).
- warn See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config
- event compiled client and server successfully in 1216 ms (311 modules)
- wait compiling...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 334 ms (311 modules)
- wait compiling /not-found (client and server)...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 694 ms (555 modules)
- warn Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload due to a runtime error.
- error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:33241
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1487:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 33241
}
- wait compiling /_error (client and server)...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 385 ms (556 modules)
```

[image]

Comment: What is supposed to be listening on port 33241? That looks like maybe an RTP port or K8s service.

Comment: Nothing, I just run nextjs and that error suddenly shows up. I'm not connecting to apis on those ports and everytime I run nextjs those ports change but same error

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to `node > v16`. Try downgrading it to `v16`.

I know this answer isn't ideal, but it seams to be a race condition between the webpack dev environment and the request to launch the environment itself.

I'm still investigating it. Keep an eye on [this issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49526)

Comment: I noticed that it fails because the listening process used tcp6 ::1:<PORT>. I did a workaround wherein I disabled tcp6 temporarily and it worked. Another workaround I did was pass `-H 127.0.0.1` which made the listeners listen using 127 instead of ::1

Answer (score 0):

Are you using nextjs new google font feature? I mean using font by importing from `'next/font/google'`?

I've just had the similar problem with a new nextjs project initialised with `npx create-next-app@latest`. By default `layout.tsx` uses this new feature:

`import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'.`
`const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })`

I commented it out and the error disappeared. I guess nextjs tries to access google servers to retrieve the fonts but fails.

Comment: I noticed that it fails because the listening process used tcp6 ::1:<PORT>. I did a workaround wherein I disabled tcp6 temporarily and it worked. Another workaround I did was pass `-H 127.0.0.1` which made the listeners listen using 127 instead of ::1